# laravel 4 changing url structure with parameter passing

Tags: forms, url, laravel, get

I'm just a beginner in laravel framework. i created a simple form and controller methods . i think by default the form method is post. but now i need to make it as get method and also wants to pass the selected inputs to controller and shows that parameters in the url also. currently i did like below but failed.

index.blade.php

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' => 'home/find','method' => 'get')); ?>
 <select class="location" id="location" name='location'>
<?php                                                
                       $id1 = /* get user db details based on locations*/  
                        $location_id_drop_down='';                       
                        foreach($idl as $lrow)
                        {
                            $city_name=Location::where('location_id','=',$lrow['loc_id'])->first();
                            if($city_name==array()) continue;
                            if(Input::old('location')==$lrow['loc_id'])
                            {
                                $location_id_drop_down.="<option value='" . $city_name['location_name'] . "' selected='selected'>" .$city_name['location_name'] . "</option>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $location_id_drop_down.="<option value='" . $city_name['location_name'] . "'>" . $city_name['location_name']. "</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        echo $location_id_drop_down;                  
                    ?>
                </select>
 <input type="submit" name="search" id="search_submit" class="search_submit" value="Search" />
 {{ Form::close() }}
```

HomeController.php

```
public function anyFind($s='',$d='',$l='') {
if(Input::get('search'))
             {

                $location=Input::get('location');
             }
             else
             {

                 if($l!='~')
                    $location=$l;
             }

/* queries to get the user details and images based on selected location and list them*/
}
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/find/{location}','HomeController@anySearch');
```

But this shows the url as `mysite.com/home/find?location=Test&search=Search`

I need mysite.com/home/find/location

is there any mistake in my code?

**Edit**

As a part of experiment i tried this method. i gave a redirect like below at the end of my controller function anyfind()

```
return Redirect::to('/home/find/'.$location);
```

But this redirects me but did anyone knows how to load the search.search_new.blade.php with this custom url??

Comment: Maybe thats not a problem in your real code but here you have an url `home/find`, a route `/search/{location}` pointing at `anySearch` and your method in the controller is `anyFind`

Comment: @lukasgeiter : no no.. sorry that was a typing mistake. actually in my code i gave it correctly.

Comment: `public function anyFind($s='',$d='',$l='') {` these parameters doesn't make any sense. you do not have those parameters in the url. you have only one in the url. you should have got a `404` error instead of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Having a field from the form in your url (not query string) is simply not possible with Laravel. What you can do though, is just use javascript for that.

First lets put a placeholder in the action url

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' => 'home/find/%location%','method' => 'get')); ?>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){ // you maybe need to be a bit more precise with the selector here
    var location = $('#location').val();
    $(this).prop('action', $(this).prop('action').replace('%location%', location));
});
```

#### Vanilla Javascript (if you can't / don't want to use jQuery)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function(e){
    var location = document.getElementById('location').value;
    e.target.setAttribute('action', e.target.getAttribute('action').replace('%location%', location));
};
```

*By the way: the code in your question has still some weird stuff in there. I'm just assuming this has happened because of copy paste etc. So if it still doesn't work, make sure you post the **correct** code*

Comment: i tried jquery and that gives me the url `home/find/%location%?location=Test&search=Search`  and the browser window shows white screen with this message `Bad request`

Comment: Looks like the javascript didn't do anything at all. Did you make sure that the javascript gets executed *after* the dom is loaded? Also, do you get any errors in the developer console?

Comment: i gave the jquery script after @section('content') in my index.blade.php . is there any mistake in that? should i gve that in any other files?

Comment: By after do you mean inside the section? If you look at the source in your browser, is the javascript code somewhere in there?

Comment: yes... inside the section content..it shows "bad request, ur server cannot understand the url" and because of that i can't even get source page on right click view page source.

Comment: You need to look at the source of the page with form and not the page it currently shows when you submit. Also try wrapping the javascript code in `$(document).ready(function(){........ });` (replace the .... with your code)

Answer (score 0):

Insert at the end of your method anyFind() inside the HomeController.php where you set the view for the page:

```
 if (Input::get('location') != '') {
        return Redirect::route('home.findByLocation',Input::get('location'));
 }

 return View::make('home', compact('location));
```

Also in your routes.php add the following code:

```
Route::get('home/find/{location?}', array('as'=>'home.findByLocation', 'uses'=>'HomeController@anyFind'));
```